# Accessing delegate of NSURLSessionTasks wrapped in static method in separate class

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I wrote a separate WebServices class for my app - WebServices.m.

In it, I have several static methods such as setUserInput(), getUserProfile(), registerNewUser(), logOutofAccount(). In those methods I include various NSURLRequests and NSURLSession tasks which successfully hit my server's endpoints.

I can easily call these static methods in various ViewControllers - 
I just do [WebServices registerNewUser]. The issue is, now I want to do the following:

1. Access the response item from the Task
2. Go to a new Viewcontroller once a Task is completely finished

I have been using completion blocks from within each completionHandler: but I assume for what I'm trying to do, I need to be using delegates instead? If so,

- How do I access the delegates if I'm using static methods in other classes?
- How can each delegate differentiate between different Tasks that are calling them?

Examples would be GREATLY appreciated since I'm pretty new to this all and I couldn't find anything pertinent on StackOverflow.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Example of static method in WebServices.m with a completion handler.

```
+(void)logOutAccount{
// 1
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mywebsite.com/logout/"];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
sessionConfig.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{@"Authorization": @"Token 123456678809203490249019203"};
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig];

// 2
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

// 3
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{};
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary
                                               options:kNilOptions error:&error];

if(!error){
    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                                                               fromData:data completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error) {
                                                                   // Handle response here
                                                                   NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
                                                                   NSLog(@"%i",httpResponse.statusCode);
                                                               }];

    // 5
    [uploadTask resume];
}
}
```

In ViewController.m viewDidLoad() I simply call [WebServices logOutAccount]. But how do I access the NSURLResponse of the completionHandler? I should be using delegates right? Which is why I was asking my questions above :)

Comment: Could you please post a code snipped implementation of any static method with `completionHandler:` and how do you use it from within your ViewController.

Comment: @EugeneDubinin I just did, can you take a look and let me know the right direction to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Completion Blocks

As [URL Session Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW1) states

> **Note:** Completion callbacks are primarily intended as an alternative to using a custom delegate. If you create a task using a method that takes a completion callback, the delegate methods for response and data delivery are not called.

So, it is OK to go with completion blocks in your case, however,

*Issue #1:* your code does not pass callbacks to caller (e.g. ViewController).

In your WebServices's header:

```
typedef void (^WebServicesCompletionHandler)(id responseObject, NSError *error);

+ (void)logOutAccountWithCompletionHandler:(WebServicesCompletionHandler)completionBlock;
```

This method, them could be used

*Issue #2:* You use `NSURLSessionUploadTask` for the API (log out) that should not upload any data to the server. Again, I don't know your server API, but I would rather go with `NSURLSessionDataTask` for this API.

```
NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask =
[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data,
                                                         NSURLResponse * _Nullable response,
                                                         NSError * _Nullable error) {
    // process response, data and error
}
[dataTask resume];
```

*Issue #3:* Your code does not actually call back

```
// if the result from the API is processed from the UI, pass them in main queue
dispatch_async_main(^{
    // make sure the caller has passed completionBlock
    if (completionBlock) {
        completionBlock(responseObject, error);
    }
});
```

So, the complete method would look like this:

```
+ (void)logOutAccountWithCompletionHandler:(WebServicesCompletionHandler)completionBlock {

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    sessionConfig.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{@"Authorization": @"Token 123456678809203490249019203"};
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mywebsite.com/logout/"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

    NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask =
    [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data,
                                                         NSURLResponse * _Nullable response,
                                                         NSError * _Nullable error) {
        dispatch_async_main(^{
            // make sure the caller has passed completionBlock
            if (completionBlock) {
                completionBlock(response, error);
            }
        });
    }];

    [dataTask resume];
}
```

You can use it from a ViewController

```
WebServicesCompletionHandler completionHandler;
completionHandler = ^(id response, NSError* error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        // process a response object
    }
    else {
        // process an error
    }
};
[WebServices logOutAccountWithCompletionHandler: completionHandler];
```

2. Delegates

Using delegates involves more things to do, so it is better to find a complete example, rather then post it here. For now, I think you are OK to try out completion blocks solution. Let me know.

**P.S.:** I would recommend to go through several tutorial out there to get more familiar with network communications (e.g. [this one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial))

Comment: Hey Eugene, this looks really promising! Thanks for the comment. Could you possibly show me an example of how to use this new method in another ViewController so that I can have access to the data/response of the DataTask? I'm a beginner so that would be extremely helpful!

Comment: Hey @Eugene Dubinin, is there a way I can message you privately? I want to pitch you something...

Comment: @stellarowl12 I don't know whether it is eligible to post any personal contacts here, on SO. Neither, I don't know is there any way to contact a person privately via SO. Let me think.